# Как вывести текст в python без ['']

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, xpath

Есть код:

```
html = parsprof.text
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.XML(html,htmlparser)
surname = tree.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/text()[2]')
name = tree.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/text()[3]')
patronymic = tree.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/text()[4]')
check_file = os.path.exists(f'photo/{chat_id}.png')
if check_file != True:
    photo = tree.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div/img/@src')
    print(photo)
if check_file == True:
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, f"photo/{chat_id}.png", caption=f' Информация о вашем аккаунте:\n\nID Telegram: {chat_id}\nID PSK: {loginpsk}\nПароль PSK: {pswdpsk[:4]}***\nДанные от ПСК\n\nИмя: {name}\nФамилия: {surname}\nОтчество: {patronymic}')
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f" Информация о вашем аккаунте:\n\nID Telegram: {chat_id}\nID PSK: {loginpsk}\nПароль PSK: {pswdpsk[:4]}***\nДанные от ПСК\n\nИмя: {name}\nФамилия: {surname}\nОтчество: {patronymic}\nАватар отсутствует!")
```

И возникла такая проблема, что данные от учетной записи, которые я собираю по средствам xpath хранятся в ['']. Я пытался удалить скобки с помощью remove и других методов которые предложил гугл. Но в итоге я получаю либо  пустые скобки, набор рандомных символов, или просто ошибку кода. Как решить проблему, и вывести текст без ['']? Заранее большое спасибо

Comment: ну это же обычный список `[]` , получить элементы внутри можно через индекс, например первый `you_variable[0]` или вы получаете строку в которой находится список?

Comment: текст выводится в боте по типу фамилия: ['Бубликов'] а мне нужно что бы выводилось фамилия: Бубликов

Comment: это список или текст? если список, то нужно обращаться к элементу как в первом комментарии, если текст, то брать срез.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавив [0] к переменной, я решил проблему. Пример:

```
surname = tree.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/text()[2]')[0]
```